# Extract numbers and letters from license plate image with Python OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to detect and then extract letters and numbers from this image. I have just started to learn OpenCV and I think that this can be done with that lib. You have the image that I used and desired output below.
This is the code that I have:

```
import cv2

# read original image
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
cv2.imshow('original', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)


# convert it to gray and apply filter 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #convert to grey scale
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#apply treshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the image:

[image]

My goal is to get separated images of each letter and number (I did this in paint):

[image]

So, what should I do to get this?
It would be perfect to keep the same order of letters and numbers, for example:

`MXF51051`

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How to select each letter and number

Comment: You can use Tesseract OCR for character recognition
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55350303/9174687

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach using simple thresholding + contour filtering

- Convert image to grayscale and Otsu's threshold
- Find contours and filter using contour area
- Extract and save ROI

---

We begin by converting to grayscale and then Otsu's threshold to obtain a binary image

[image]

Next we find contours using `cv2.findContours()`. To keep the same order of letters/numbers, we use [`imutils.contours.sort_contours()`](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/blob/master/imutils/contours.py) with the `left-to-right` parameter to ensure that when we iterate through the contours, we have each contour in the correct order. For each contour, we filter using a minimum and maximum area threshold to ensure that we only keep contours with the desired text. Once we have the filtered ROI, we extract/save the ROI using Numpy slicing. Here's the filtered mask with only the desired text

[image]

Detected numbers and letters

[image]

The extracted ROIs in the correct order

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from imutils import contours

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right")
ROI_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 800 and area > 200:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ROI = 255 - thresh[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)
        cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
        ROI_number += 1

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```